# Semantic-Ui: How to pass arguments from popup elements to popup contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm trying to access the element that triggered the popup, through popup
contents ("Click me" button in my example), so I used a **non-global** variable ("source_element" in the example) as a workaround.

**HTML Code:**

```
<button id="show-popup-btn1" class="ui green button">
  Show popup 1
</button>

<button id="show-popup-btn2" class="ui red button">
  Show popup 2
</button>

<div class="ui popup">
  <button id="click-me-button" class="ui blue button">
    Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code** :

```
var source_element,
    popup = {
      popup: $('.ui.popup'),
      on: 'click',
      onShow: function(element) {
        source_element = element;
      }
    };

$('#show-popup-btn1').popup(popup);
$('#show-popup-btn2').popup(popup);

$('#click-me-button').on('click', function() {
  alert('The source element is: ' + source_element.innerText);
  $('button').popup('hide');
});
```

**Here is the code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmXBqz)**

Is there a **better way** to do that ? an official way maybe ?

> **Note:** Please, feel free to adjust the code.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any better way to do this, but little changes to your code eliminating the non-global variable

```
var popup = {
  popup: $('.ui.popup'),
  on: 'click',
  onShow: function(element) {
    $('#click-me-button').off("click")
    $('#click-me-button').on('click', function() {
        alert('The source element is: ' +element.innerText);
        $('button').popup('hide');
    });
  }
};
$('#show-popup-btn1').popup(popup);
$('#show-popup-btn2').popup(popup);
```